# Error while playing Audio in browser

Tags: javascript

I am playing audio with user specified starttime using javascript code

```
var audio_player = document.getElementById("audi");
//'audi' is ID of audio tag  
audio_player.currentTime = audi_start_time;
//Start time from where audio should start to play

audio_player.play();
```

when I run website I'm able to play the audio from the time specified in 'audi_start_time' but most of the time I'm getting error

> 'An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable
>   [Break On This Error]

```
audio_player.currentTime = audi_start_time;
```

Any help would be appreciated. thanks in advance

Comment: what is "reply" in your code?

Comment: Reply is JSON object, you can just ignore it. audi_start_time contains the start time for audio,

Answer (score 2):

I think you are trying to set `currentTime` before document ready,

because it's working when you set currentTime in window.onlaoad.

here is what you are trying to do  -> [jsFiddle demo-1](http://jsfiddle.net/Smuh8/1) (**not working**)

here is what you should do -> [jsFiddle demo-2](http://jsfiddle.net/Smuh8) (**working**)

---

**EDIT:**

Ok, I got it. If you are trying to set `currentTime` of audio/video tag that appended dynamically, you should wait for audio tag to be ready to play.

So you can detect it with [oncanplay event](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#event-media-canplay),

for example,

```
<div id="content"></div>
<button onclick="play()">play</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
function play() {
     var audio = document.createElement("audio");
     audio.controls = "controls";
     audio.innerHTML = '<source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html5/song.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />'+
                       '<source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html5/song.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />';
     var content = document.getElementById("content");
     content.innerHTML = "";
     content.appendChild(audio);
     audio.addEventListener("canplay", function() {
        this.currentTime = 5;        
     },true);
     audio.play();
}
</script>​
```

and [here is a working jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ocanal/Smuh8/2/)

Comment: actually I am dealing with both audio and video,I have not hard coded the tags. when we drag and drop the files the tags are created so your code works only with hard coded tags in HTML. So please tell me what should i do to set the current time dynamically

Comment: your updated code is not exactly playing, but getting stuck on the start time of the track till the specified end time.I could hear only beep sound for that particular specified time..

Comment: @SagarHugar, the last jsFiddle demo is working in google chrome. sorry, don't know why it's not working for you.

Answer (score 0):

Play the audio before you set current time. I beat my head on the desk all night over this, and then I found this thread: https://github.com/johndyer/mediaelement/issues/243. This ended up working for me:

```
audioplayer.src = source;
audioplayer.play();
audioplayer.addEventListener('playing', function () {
    if (loadPlayed == false)
    {
        audioplayer.currentTime = Time;
        audioplayer.play();
        loadPlayed = true;
    }
    else {
        audioplayer.removeEventListener('playing', this);
    }
});
```

Comment: Instead of creating a loadPlayed variable you can specify the once option in addEventListener:

`audioplayer.addEventListener('playing', function() {}, { once: true })`